# How to Update Data in Database while Downloading a File in Asp (For counting number of times Files downloaded)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Just want to count how many times a file has been downloaded from my website. For that, first, i have used this code:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    int id = (int)Session["idu"];

    byte[] bytes;
    string fileName, contentType, btype, date, visited;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand c2 = new SqlCommand())
        {
            c2.Connection = con;
            c2.CommandTimeout = 1500;
            c2.CommandText = "UPDATE Publication SET downloads= downloads+1 where id='" + Session["idu"] + "'";
            // c2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader s = c2.ExecuteReader();
            s.Read();





        } con.Close();



        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {    
            cmd.CommandText = "select fname, data, ftype,btype,date,visited,downloads from Publication where id=@Id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            con.Open();

            cmd.Connection = con;


            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["data"];
                contentType = sdr["ftype"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["fname"].ToString();
                btype = sdr["btype"].ToString();
                date = sdr["date"].ToString();
                visited = sdr["visited"].ToString();
               downloads = (int)sdr["downloads"];


            }



        }




        con.Close();

    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = contentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);

    Response.Flush();





    Response.End();

}
```

here Session["idu"] is the id value which were fetched from the linkbutton in gridview from the previous page. All i want that, when i hit Button1, first i want to update the value of downloads, then download the file. For this, i used CommandTimeout 1500 seconds to get enough time execute updating. This code is Working for Small files like size of 186 KB . But for large file, like 1 MB, I got Error of Time Expiration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDAvS.png)

Why does it appear? How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Your error not from this page

Comment: In error you may see GridView, but in your code there are no gridviews. So error is in another page or you didn't posted the whole code

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you read the entire file content from the DB when calling `bytes = (byte[])sdr["data"];`. This explains why your query only times out for big files. Using the `Stream` class for the file contents could be a starting point.

ASP MVC supports a `FileStreamResult` to stream big files to the client, but I am not sure how to do this in classic ASP.